# Shop software for a very large shop

Tags: cms, shopping-cart

At the moment I'm using Joomla with [HikaShop](http://www.hikashop.com/) for a shop with around 35 000 products with their variants, but this is getting too large (too slow).

Properties of the shop are:

1. Product has variants: color & size = combined
2. Product has prices are set on variants, for example: blue & 6cm = 30usd, blue & 8cm = 35usd
3. Every variant has 2 prices, the first one for the general public and the second one for a special user group
4. Shipping methods are possible per user group and country

Requirements for the shop engine:

1. Support large number of items
2. Handle all properties which are listed above
3. Speed (at the moment we use a very big cache systems and other methods but the site is too slow)
4. A SEO friendly URL structure without needs to buy an extra extension for URLs
5. Multilingual support because this shop has over 5 languages

I tested [Prestashop](https://www.prestashop.com/en/) with [Magento](https://magento.com/), but would like hear from others what shop software is recommended for my needs.

Comment: May be can try with Umbraco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SAP Hybris Commerce

Disclaimer: I am working for SAP

From Hybris perspective 35 000 products is a small shop. Hybris can do everything you want and through extensions you can add functionality. But it has a price tag ;-)
Depending on your future plans this might be something to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it would be an option for you to consider, but Drupal (one of the typical alternatives for Joomla), has an impressive [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart)" solution which I think would get you pretty far in what you're looking for. Here is a quote about it:

> Commerce Kickstart is the quickest way to get up and running with Drupal Commerce. It includes the latest versions of Drupal core, [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), and the other modules it depends on. It also gives you a set of options to create a fully-featured demo store out of the box complete with an attractive theme, catalog and search configuration, and a custom back office interface.

And here is a [real world sample](http://www.permantiermotors.be/) of site created with it. Created by somebody who just got started with Drupal, with hardly any budget, but even multi-language (English, French, Dutch ...).

Comment: I thought drupal had died a long slow death. Drupal 8 has been in the works for what... 10 years?